# Access is denied spring security even when user is logged in

Tags: java, spring, azure, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using spring security in my web application the authentication works fine i got redirected to the home page after login , the logged in username is shown in my application and everything is good except for one thing .
I have an upload method in my application where the user can upload a video to azure storage and then save the url in the database 
This is the upload methode

```
    public String fileUpload(File fileUp, String fileN) {

    try {
        fileN = fileN.replace(" ", "_");
        // Retrieve storage account from connection-string.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionStringU);

        // Create the blob client.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();

        // Get a reference to a container.
        // The container name must be lower case
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("filescontainer");

        System.out.println("exist " + container.exists());
        // Create the container if it does not exist.
        container.createIfNotExists();

        // Allow Public Access
        BlobContainerPermissions containerPermissions = new BlobContainerPermissions();

        // Include public access in the permissions object.
        containerPermissions.setPublicAccess(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.CONTAINER);

        // Set the permissions on the container.
        container.uploadPermissions(containerPermissions);

        // Create or overwrite the blob with contents from a local file.
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(fileN);

        ServiceProperties serviceProperties = blob.getServiceClient().downloadServiceProperties();
        serviceProperties.setDefaultServiceVersion("2019-07-07");
        blob.getServiceClient().uploadServiceProperties(serviceProperties);

        /* // Plan B
         * RequestOptions RequestOptions =
         * blob.getServiceClient().getDefaultRequestOptions();
         * // <Can Set Timeout Here> 
         * RequestOptions.setTimeoutIntervalInMs(?);
         */

        // Used StreamWriteSize to break the file into blocks to avoid timeout
        blob.setStreamWriteSizeInBytes(1024*1024);

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileUp);
        blob.upload(in, fileUp.length());
        return containerUrl+fileN;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Output the stack trace.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "";

}
```

And this is my upload controller

```
    @PostMapping("/addVideo")
public String uploadMultipleFiles(@RequestParam("vdLength") String vdLength,
        @RequestParam("files1") MultipartFile files1){

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int readByteCount = 0;
    VideoFile vd = new VideoFile();

    File target = new File(ownerID + fileNameVd + "_" + date.getTime() + ".mp4");
    try(BufferedInputStream in= new BufferedInputStream(files1.getInputStream());
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(target)) {

    while((readByteCount = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {

    out.write(buffer, 0, readByteCount);
                    }
            out.close();
            }
vd.setVideoURL(new UploadAzurController().fileUpload(target,ownerID + fileNameVd + "_" + date.getTime() + ".mp4"));
target.delete();    
videoService.addVideo(vd);}
```

The upload sometime work and sometimes it show 
502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.
And i find in the stacktrace this :

> 2020-04-23T11:01:46.390408136Z 11:01:46.382 [http-nio-80-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@dab9512f: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff4c9c: RemoteIpAddress: 172.16.1.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.391507942Z 11:01:46.391 [http-nio-80-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@1928c84c, returned: -1
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.393975556Z 11:01:46.393 [http-nio-80-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.393991456Z org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.393996856Z  at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394001156Z  at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394005056Z  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394008856Z  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394012656Z  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394016356Z  at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394020156Z  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394023856Z  at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394027656Z  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394031356Z  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394035156Z  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394038956Z  at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394042856Z  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394046556Z  at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394050356Z  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394054756Z  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394058656Z  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394062356Z  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394066156Z  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394076756Z  at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394080756Z  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394084556Z  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394088256Z  at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394092156Z  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394095856Z  at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394099656Z  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394103456Z  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394107256Z  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394110956Z  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394114656Z  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394118456Z  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394122156Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394125856Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394129556Z  at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394133657Z  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394137457Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394141157Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394144957Z  at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394148657Z  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394152357Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394156057Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394159857Z  at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394166457Z  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394170157Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394173957Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394177757Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394181757Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394185657Z  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394189357Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394193057Z  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394196757Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394200457Z  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394204057Z  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394207857Z  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394211557Z  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394215157Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394219357Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394223057Z  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394226757Z  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394230457Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   2020-04-23T11:01:46.394234257Z  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

This is my sping security config class

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("datasource")
    private DataSource dataSource;
    public static Boolean anon;
    @Value("${role.anonymous}")
    public void setAnon(Boolean anon) {
        this.anon = anon;
    }
    // Secure the endpoins with HTTP Basic authentication
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        if (anon) {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll().antMatchers("/Search/**").permitAll();
        }
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/manager*").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "MANAGER")
        .antMatchers("/uploadFile").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "MANAGER")
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/footer**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/header**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().csrf().disable().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/");
    }
    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() {
        try {
            return super.userDetailsServiceBean();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    @Bean
    public SwitchUserFilter switchUserFilter() {
        SwitchUserFilter filter = new SwitchUserFilter();
        filter.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsServiceBean());
        filter.setUsernameParameter("username");
        filter.setSwitchUserUrl("/switch_user");
        filter.setExitUserUrl("/switch_user_exit");
        filter.setTargetUrl("/");
        return filter;
    }

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
            "Select auth.username, auth.authority , 1 as enabled from (select A.username, A.authority  from admin as A UNION select M.username, M.authority from manager as M UNION select U.username, U.authority from user as U UNION select R.username, R.authority from readeruser as R)  auth WHERE auth.username = ? ")
            .usersByUsernameQuery(
                    "Select auth.username, auth.password , 1 as enabled from (select A.username, A.password ,1 as enabled from admin as A UNION select M.username, M.password ,1 as enabled from manager as M UNION select U.username, U.password ,1 as enabled from user as U UNION select R.username, R.password ,1 as enabled from readeruser as R) auth WHERE auth.username = ?  ");
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public HttpFirewall allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall() {
    StrictHttpFirewall firewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
    firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedSlash(true);
    return firewall;
}
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/*.css");
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/*.js");
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/*.png");
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/videos/*.mp4");
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/videos/*.png");
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/videos/*.vtt");

    web.httpFirewall(allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall());
}
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*"); // this allows all origin
    config.addAllowedHeader("*"); // this allows all headers
    config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
    config.addAllowedMethod("HEAD");
    config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PATCH");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**");
}
}
```

After the upload fail and I go to the application I find that the user is still logged in .
I hope that i provided all the needed information so you can help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was because that the application is hosted to azure service and there is a request timeout 230s which you can't change so i changed my upload method to Async upload and everything works fine right now .

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing your file size upload.

```
#### File upload config ####
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=xxMB/GB/etc
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=xxMB/GB/etc
```

Comment: Well then I'd say use the debugger and see what that tells you.